# Proving that equation has at least one solution in the interval (-1,1)

Tags: calculus

We are given two numbers $a>0$ and $b>0$ and the equation given is

$$ \frac{a}{x^3 + 2x^2 - 1} + \frac{b}{x^3 + x - 2} = 0 $$

Prove that this equation has at least one solution in the interval $(-1,1)$. Now I can let

$$ f(x) = \frac{a}{x^3 + 2x^2 - 1} + \frac{b}{x^3 + x - 2} $$

And then I can think of using intermediate value theorem (IVT) on the interval $[-1,1]$. But the problem is that $ x^3 + 2x^2 - 1 $ has zeroes at $-1$ and $0.618$ and $x^3 + x - 2$ has a real zero at $1$. So, that means that $f(x)$ is not continuous on $[-1,1]$. So, how can IVT be used here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two cubics  do not have a common root.That can be exploited as follows:

Let $g(x)=a(x^{3}+x-2)+b(x^{3}+2x^{2}-1)$.  Then $g(1)=2b>0$ and $g(-1)=-4a<0$. Hence, there exists $x \in (-1,1)$ such that $g(x)=0$. At this point $x$ neither $x^{3}+x-2$ nor $x^{3}+2x^{2}-1$ can be $0$: If $x^{3}+x-2=0$ we get $g(x)=b(x^{3}+2x^{2}-1)\neq 0$ and if $x^{3}+2x^{2}-1=0$ then $g(x)=a(x^{3}+x-2) \neq 0$. Hence, we can divide the equation $g(x)=0$ by $(x^{3}+x-2) (x^{3}+2x^{2}-1)$.

EDIT: A simple proof of the fact that the two cubics do not have a common root is posted below by user2661923

Comment: I don't get why $g(x) = b(x^3 + 2x^2 - 1) \ne 0$. If both cubic are zero, then how is this possible ?

Comment: You have already looked at the roots of the cubics and found that there is no common root. If one of the cubics is $0$ then th other one is not $0$.  So if $x^{3}+2x^{2}-1=0$ then $x^{3}+x-2 \neq 0$. Similarly, in the other case.  @user9026

Comment: @user9026 Let $r(x) = (x^3 + 2x^2 - 1)$ and let $s(x) = (x^3 + x - 2)$.  If $~\exists ~x_0~$ such that $r(x_0) = 0 = s(x_0),~$ then $[r(x_0) - s(x_0)] = 0.~$  However, $$r(x) - s(x) = 0 \implies (2x^2 - x + 1) = 0,$$ which is impossible, since the discriminant, $(1 - 8)$ is $< 0$.  Now, suppose that there is an $x_1$, such that $ar(x_1) + bs(x_1) = 0.$  You can not have $r(x_1) = 0 = s(x_1).$  If $r(x_1) = 0$, then $bs(x_1) = 0 ~: ~$ contradiction.  Similarly, if $s(x_1) = 0$, then $r(x_1) = 0 ~: ~$ contradiction.  Thus, sufficient to show that $ar(x) + bs(x)$ crosses the $x$-axis in $[-1,1].$

Comment: +1 to your answer : I tried to find an alternate proof, but couldn't avoid using that the two cubics can't have a common root.  Therefore, I couldn't find a way to improve on your answer, which I suspect is the answer that the problem composer intended.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for your comments. I have given a reference to your comment in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.